# seed-fu not working on winxp

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have seed-fu installed on my mac book, no problems.

But I can install it fine on winxp but when I run it, I get:

```
Don't know how to bulid task db:seed
```

I checked my installed directory (c:\ruby\libs) and it appears to be there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vendor/plugin files were missing. I checked them and resynced on the xp machine and that fixed it. Hopefully this can help someone else.